# Understanding Debian domain name

Tags: debian, networking

I am specifically referring to the "Domain name" prompt that appears during system setup. I understand that the value entered on this prompt is inserted into `/etc/resolv.conf` as the following.

```
search mydomain.local
domain mydomain.local
```

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/889456/correct-domain-name-for-a-home-desktop-linux-machine) answer leads me to believe that two debian systems (let's say `deb1` and `deb2`) on the same unmanaged network (let's say connected to a network switch or hub) would be able to search for each others hostnames and be able to ping each other. Although when I install two debian virtual machines, with identical settings, although different hostnames, no communication is possible from `deb2` whether through pinging `deb1` or `deb1.mydomain.local` (or vice-versa). I also have no communication through IPv6 link-local, which I am under the impression should be completely auto-configured.

Is there something wrong with the setup I have, or is this type of communication not possible through an unmanaged setup?

Comment: Depends on how you've virtualized them and how you've connected them.  As an example, the default network type in VirtualBox is NAT and there is no connectivity to other machines on hte NAT network.  You could use Internal Only or Host Only or Bridged and they'd be able to communicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a search domain does it is provides a domain name that is appended to name resolution queries that contain less dots (a `.`) in them than whatever the ndots option is set to in `/etc/resolv.conf` (default is 1). ([`resolv.conf` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf), see `search` section.)

This means that if my `resolv.conf` specifies `search corp.org` and I have a host `mailsvr.corp.org` that I wish to connect to I can use the hostname `mailsvr` for my connections because `corp.org` is automatically appended to any hostnames with less than one `.`.

As to why you cannot communicate between your two boxes despite the IPv6 auto-configuration, if your virtual machines are not configured to resolve the hostname of the other to an IPv6 address through DNS or mapping in your [`/etc/hosts`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts) file then they do not know where to send packets. So if `deb1` is ::10, `deb2` does not know this. If you try `ping deb1` from `deb2` you will receive the error `Unknown host deb1`. You can add a line to `deb2`'s `/etc/hosts` file with the address of `deb1` mapped to its hostname, e.g. `::10 deb1`. The same thing will need to be done on `deb1` with `deb2`'s address mapped to it's IP address in so that `deb1` knows what address `deb2` has too.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. Though, if I were to ignore the DNS part of this, and `ping -6 ::10` from `deb2` would that still work through IPv6 auto-configuration?

Comment: @Hidden14 Yes, pinging directly by IP address will work without any need to futz with the `hosts` file.

Comment: @Hidden14 I'm sorry, I forgot to add that I was assuming the virtual networking was configured in a manner that allows the machines to communicate with each other. I don't know much about that so if they can't communicate by IP directly, it may be worth further research and/or opening another question on the topic.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. I have the vm's communicating. The IPv6 issue was a misuse of the command `ping6` command instead of the comms itself. Link local works great.